# Android Adwhirl shows Unsupported Ration Type

Tags: android, adwhirl

By looking at this link i tried to implement Adwhirl in android

> https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/android/AdWhirlAndroidSDKSetup.html

I created accounts in both admob and Adwhirl.
The adwhirl request in going....

But my LOG shows

```
: Rotating Ad
: Dart is <64.45885525893553> of <100.0>
04-26 09:01:34.164: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322): Showing ad:
04-26 09:01:34.164: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322):     nid: c2f1ad5211f0471d84002ae595aafe37
04-26 09:01:34.164: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322):     name: admob
04-26 09:01:34.164: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322):     type: 1
04-26 09:01:34.164: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322):     key: a14cc177ec52af5
04-26 09:01:34.164: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322):     key2: 
04-26 09:01:34.204: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322): Unsupported ration type: 1
04-26 09:01:34.373: DEBUG/dalvikvm(322): GC freed 8949 objects / 767976 bytes in 155ms
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322): Caught an exception in adapter:
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322): java.lang.Exception: Invalid adapter
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.handle(AdWhirlAdapter.java:166)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:222)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$3(AdWhirlLayout.java:205)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:390)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4338)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-26 09:01:34.383: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 09:01:34.395: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(322): nextRation is null!
04-26 09:01:34.395: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(322): Will call rotateAd() in 30 seconds
04-26 09:02:04.463: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(322): Rotating Ad
```

I think this is creating problem

```
04-26 09:01:34.204: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(322): Unsupported ration type: 1
```

Any solutions...plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the AdMob SDK in your project's build path? Check out these [instructions](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addjar).

Comment: Yes, AdWhirl is just an ad "mediator". Which means it's basically a tool that displays ads from **other** ad networks. They don't actually have ads themselves, all the ads come from real ad networks such as AdMob or Millennial Media. So if you want to get your ads from AdMob, then you need to install/setup the SDK from AdWirl as well as AdMob in your project. You will also need to register with AdMob to get a key and provide that info to AdWhirl.

Comment: Ya i take the pulisher ID from the admob and put in the Adwhirl. But i do not included the admob sdk in my project. Thanks for your insight

Comment: No problem. Don't forget you also have to [include changes](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#adactivity) to your manifest (adding a "activity" and also permissions) in order for AdMob to work. For every additional ad network you want to use, you'll also have to install their respective SDKs and possibly add some more entries into your manifest (instructions vary slightly depending on the network and how their programmers wanted to do things). The reason you need these ad SDKs is because AdWhirl makes calls to code in these SDKs (even though you don't see it).